# Как создать url для переадресации?

Tags: php, html, yii2, bootstrap

Изучаю yii2 и столкнулся с проблемой. Хотел узнать, как просто добавить еще кнопки для переадресации соответсвенно - редактирование (`projects/views/update`), полная информация (`projects/views/view`) с учетом выбранного id.

Код который уже есть для вывода в dropdown button:

```
<?php

use backend\models\Tasks;
use yii\bootstrap5\Modal;
use yii\grid\ActionColumn;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/** @var yii\web\View $this */
/** @var backend\models\Projects $model */
/** @var backend\models\Tasks $model */

$this->title = $model->name;
\yii\web\YiiAsset::register($this);
?>
<div class="projects-view">
    <p>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i>
    </button>
        <?php
        Modal::begin([
            'title' => '<h4>Приглашение в проект</h4>',
            'toggleButton' => [
                'label' => '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>',
                'class' => 'btn btn-secondary',],
        ]);

        Modal::end();?>
        <?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>',['/tasks/create','project_id'=>$model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-success ',]); ?>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <?php
        foreach ($model->getProjects() as $project)
            echo '<li></li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/projects/index">'.$project->name.'</a> 
        </li>'
        ?>

    </ul>
</div>

    <p></p>
    <p>Наименование: <?= $model ->name?></p>

    <p>Описание: <?= $model ->description?></p>

    <p>Статус: <?= $model::$statuses[$model->status]?></p>



    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $model->getTasks(),
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['label' => 'Наименование',
                'attribute' => 'name',],
            ['label' => 'Описание',
                'attribute' => 'description',],
            ['label' => 'Исполнитель',
                'attribute' => 'executor_id',],
            ['label' => 'Куратор',
                'attribute' => 'curator_id',],
            [
                'attribute' => 'status',
                'label'=>'Статус',
                'value' => static function ($model) {
                    return $model::$statuses[$model->status];
                }
            ] ,
            [
                'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
                'urlCreator' => function ($action, Tasks $model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return Url::toRoute([$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

И вот что он выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался реализовать, догадался, что можно как то url вписывать в `<li> </li>`. Но не хватает понимания как это сделать)
А вот что я хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем в канун 2024 года изучать yii2 вообще? Вы посмотрите вообще на верстку которую этот код генерирует, вряд ли она синтаксически корректна. Как и `foreach` в вашем коде, разве что yii там чудо-юдо предпобработку/компиляцию шаблона не делает, в чем я сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте использовать в columns это (view, update, delete можно не переопределять):

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view} {link} {update} {deactivate} {delete}',
    'buttons' => [
        'view' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a(
                text/icon,
                url,
                options
            );
        },
        'link' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a(
                text/icon,
                url,
                options
            );
        },
        'update' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a(
                text/icon,
                url,
                options
            );
        },
        'deactivate' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a(
                text/icon,
                url,
                options
            );
        },
        'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a(
                text/icon,
                url,
                options
            );
        },
    ],
]
```